# MongoDB - Checking to see if multiple fields exist in a collection

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for a way to see if two fields already exist in an collection.Ive been reading the docs but they dont seem to be helping too much.
I have seen that you can use $exist but can this compare multiple fields at the same time?

How would I go about achieving this?

I have a collection with something like this

```
{userId: ObjectId("57840667f862724c0f736a69"), artId: ObjectId("5783e368b30fb4482ba390eb")}
```

I want to check to see if this collection contains both

```
userId:ObjectId("57840667f862724c0f736a69") && artId: ObjectId("5783e368b30fb4482ba390eb")
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use [`and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) and [`$exist`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/).

```
db.collection.find({
  $and : [
    { userId: { $exists: true } },
    { artId : { $exists: true } }
  ]
})
```

Comment: I will definitely check this out! Thank you so much!!

Comment: `db.collection.find({userId : {$exists : true}, artId : {$exists : true}})` will also get you what you need. `$and` makes more sense when you need to match same field with different criteria.Just pointing out.